# Increment value based on field check in dataweave

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

```
<tXML>
  <Header>
    <Source>J1_RETAIL</Source>
    <Action_Type>Update</Action_Type>
    <Sequence_Number>0</Sequence_Number>
    <Batch_ID>4383352</Batch_ID>
    <Reference_ID>04381645</Reference_ID>
    <User_ID>SAP</User_ID>
    <Password>password</Password>
    <Message_Type>SAP_DO</Message_Type>
    <Company_ID>J1</Company_ID>
    <Msg_Locale>English (United States)</Msg_Locale>
    <Msg_Time_Zone>Eastern Standard Time</Msg_Time_Zone>
    <Version></Version>
    <Internal_Reference_ID></Internal_Reference_ID>
    <Internal_Date_Time_Stamp></Internal_Date_Time_Stamp>
    <External_Reference_ID></External_Reference_ID>
    <External_Date_Time_Stamp></External_Date_Time_Stamp>
  </Header>
  <Message>
    <DistributionOrder>
        <ProcessInfo>
            <RefTextField1></RefTextField1>
            <RefTextField2></RefTextField2>
            <RefTextField3>S082</RefTextField3>
            <RefTextField4></RefTextField4>
            <RefTextField5></RefTextField5>
            <RefTextField6></RefTextField6>
            <RefTextField7>J1</RefTextField7>
            <RefTextField8>[0001333006_SAPTOMIF]</RefTextField8>
            <RefTextField9></RefTextField9>
            <RefTextField10>[ _20191223]</RefTextField10>
            <RefNumberField1>20191220</RefNumberField1>
            <RefNumberField2>34621</RefNumberField2>
            <RefNumberField3></RefNumberField3>
            <RefNumberField4>53</RefNumberField4>
            <RefNumberField5>13</RefNumberField5>
        </ProcessInfo>
        <Comment>
            <NoteType>MB</NoteType>
            <NoteCode>05</NoteCode>
            <CommentText>[00000_8769_741_82_093_965_987_456]</CommentText>
            <Visibility>0</Visibility>
          </Comment>
          <CustomFieldList>
            <CustomField>
              <Name>SiteID</Name>
              <Value></Value>
            </CustomField>
        <LineItem>
            <DoLineNbr>1</DoLineNbr>
            <ItemName>135465</ItemName>
            <Description>A</Description>
            <UpdateActionType></UpdateActionType>
            <PackageType></PackageType>
            <DoLineStatus>Released</DoLineStatus>
            <InventoryAttributes>
              <InventoryType>F</InventoryType>
              <ProductStatus></ProductStatus>
              <BatchNbr></BatchNbr>
              <CountryOfOrigin></CountryOfOrigin>
              <ItemAttribute1>R</ItemAttribute1>
              <ItemAttribute2></ItemAttribute2>
              <ItemAttribute3></ItemAttribute3>
              <ItemAttribute4></ItemAttribute4>
              <ItemAttribute5></ItemAttribute5>
            </InventoryAttributes>
        </LineItem>
    </DistributionOrder>
  </Message>
</tXML>
```

My code looks like this

```
output application/csv header = false , separator = "|" , quoteValues = false
---
payload.tXML.Message.*DistributionOrder map ((DistributionOrder , indexofDistributionOrder) ->  {
    column_1: "000000001",
    column_2: "0",
    column_3: "0",
    column_4: (LineItem.LineProcessInfo.LineRefTextField2 splitBy "_")[0] replace "[" with "" default "",
    column_5: (LineItem.LineProcessInfo.LineRefTextField2 splitBy "_")[1] replace "[" with "" default "",
    column_6: ????
    column_7: "",
    column_8: "",
    column_9: "",
    column_10: "",
})
```

for `column_6` condition is if the if `NoteType = MB` and `NoteCode =05` and I have to loop over each comment text and under `DistributionOrder` `[00000_8769_741_82_093_965_987_456]` and there are 8[0 to 7] values separated by underscore. I need to check if the values from 1 to 7 are coming then if value is not empty assign incremental 01 to 07. if one of the value is coming as empty then skip that number assign next number (for example if 5th value is coming empty then skip 05 and assign 06).

Comment: Can you add one or more output examples using the same data to understand better what do you need to achieve? I don't get where the 8 values you mention end.

Comment: <Comment>
            <NoteType>MB</NoteType>
            <NoteCode>05</NoteCode>
            <CommentText>[00000_8769_741_82_ _ _987_456]</CommentText>
            <Visibility>0</Visibility>
          </Comment>
000000001|0|0|||01||||
000000001|0|0|||02||||
000000001|0|0|||03||||
000000001|0|0|||06|||| 
000000001|0|0||| 07|||| in the above example 4th element and 5th are missing then i have to skip those numbers like above

Answer (score 0):

Your request seem to be to increment a counter based on a string. It seems a bit confusing. I would redefine it as counting not empty values separated by the '_' character in the CommentText element which is a string.

Then I would express column 6 as:

```
column_6: sizeOf( (DistributionOrder.Comment.CommentText splitBy  ('_')) filter (not isBlank($) ))
```

For the input:

```
<CommentText>[00000_8769_741_82_ _ _987_456]</CommentText>
```

the output is 6.